# ASP.NET Core w/Angular Template - httpget Route is being caught by Angular - cannot match any routes

Tags: angular, asp.net-core

I am currently working on an ASP.NET Core Web App with the Angular template provided by Visual Studio 2019 - everything is working beautifully until I try to hit an ASP.NET Core api route, namely a simple HTTPGET with the default route provided by scaffolding the database models, which I scaffolded by pulling in the Azure SQL database into the SQL Object Explorer. I also scaffolded my controllers based on the models so all of the api routes I'm currently working with are the default CRUD operations.

When I visit my application at localhost:port/api/enrolees, I receive this angular error:

> Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'api/enrolees'

I can clearly see that Angular is snagging the api route and treating it as an Angular route. So, I tried adding url rewrite rules in my web.config as follows:

```
<rule name="AngularJS" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(api)" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
        </rule>
```

However, this makes the application unable to find the css files and still throws the error when I try to access the route. I should mention that the default controller built into the application, WeatherForecast, works just fine.

If I change my httpget request to return just a string, then the url http://localhost:port/api/enrolees returns the string as expected.

When I debug the code and hit the api/controller directly, I receive a System.NotImplementedException which states:

> The function or method is not implemented.

Apart from this, I have set up function that calls a service which calls the api route and all of that gets hit as expected but returns as undefined. It is clear that something is not set up correctly. I have been struggling for hours and have been unable to find a suitable solution here or on Google.

My startup file

```
using Hackathon.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.AngularCli;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

namespace Hackathon
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            // In production, the Angular files will be served from this directory
            services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
            {
                configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/dist";
            });

            services.AddDbContext<SQContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

            services.AddCors(o =>
            {
                o.AddPolicy("AllowAllHeaders", builder =>
                {
                    builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                    .AllowAnyMethod()
                    .AllowAnyHeader();
                });
            });
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseCors("AllowAllHeaders");

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });

            app.UseSpa(spa =>
            {
                // To learn more about options for serving an Angular SPA from ASP.NET Core,
                // see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=864501

                spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

            });
        }
    }
}
```

My controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Hackathon.Models;

namespace Hackathon.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class EnroleesController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly SQContext _context;

        public EnroleesController(SQContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        // GET: api/Enrolees
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Enrolee>>> GetEnrolee()
        {
            var list = await _context.Enrolee.ToListAsync();
            return list;
        }

        // GET: api/Enrolees/5
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Enrolee>> GetEnrolee(int id)
        {
            var enrolee = await _context.Enrolee.FindAsync(id);

            if (enrolee == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return enrolee;
        }

        // PUT: api/Enrolees/5
        // To protect from overposting attacks, enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for
        // more details, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2123754.
        [HttpPut("{id}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> PutEnrolee(int id, Enrolee enrolee)
        {
            if (id != enrolee.EnroleeId)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }

            _context.Entry(enrolee).State = EntityState.Modified;

            try
            {
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if (!EnroleeExists(id))
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }

            return NoContent();
        }

        // POST: api/Enrolees
        // To protect from overposting attacks, enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for
        // more details, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2123754.
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Enrolee>> PostEnrolee(Enrolee enrolee)
        {
            _context.Enrolee.Add(enrolee);
            try
            {
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateException)
            {
                if (EnroleeExists(enrolee.EnroleeId))
                {
                    return Conflict();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }

            return CreatedAtAction("GetEnrolee", new { id = enrolee.EnroleeId }, enrolee);
        }

        // DELETE: api/Enrolees/5
        [HttpDelete("{id}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Enrolee>> DeleteEnrolee(int id)
        {
            var enrolee = await _context.Enrolee.FindAsync(id);
            if (enrolee == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            _context.Enrolee.Remove(enrolee);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return enrolee;
        }

        private bool EnroleeExists(int id)
        {
            return _context.Enrolee.Any(e => e.EnroleeId == id);
        }
    }
}
```

My app.module:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NavMenuComponent } from './nav-menu/nav-menu.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { CounterComponent } from './counter/counter.component';
import { FetchDataComponent } from './fetch-data/fetch-data.component';
import { TemplateComponent } from './template/template.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { RegistrationComponent } from './registration/registration.component';
import { MaterialModule } from './material/material.module';
import { EnroleesService } from './services/enrolees.service';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NavMenuComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    CounterComponent,
    FetchDataComponent,
    TemplateComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    RegistrationComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule.withServerTransition({ appId: 'ng-cli-universal' }),
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      { path: '', component: HomeComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: 'counter', component: CounterComponent },
      { path: 'fetch-data', component: FetchDataComponent },
      { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
      { path: 'register', component: RegistrationComponent }
    ]),
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MaterialModule
  ],
  providers: [ EnroleesService ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I don't think any other information is needed. My angular.json is the default file, as is my package.json apart from the nuget packages I have installed. I am publishing this to IIS through Visual Studio. I must be missing something!

Any help would be appreciated! TIA!

Comment: how are you running the application?

Comment: @ESG I am deploying through Visual Studio - publishing to a folder in my C:\inetpub\wwwroot directory with an app pool of "no managed code". I created a website in IIS for it on port 8011.

Comment: What is being outputted to that folder on publish? Normally the aspnet core stack should be serving the angular files, and you shouldn't need to do anything in angular to ignore the api routes

Comment: Yes, that is what I have experienced with previous applications I've built this way. The root folder contains the ASP.NET Core files plus the ClientApp Angular directory, which holds the dist folder and inside, the Angular files. I also copy and paste the angular files into the wwwroot directory of the application folder (c:\inetpub\wwwroot\application\wwwroot).

Comment: That's the issue then. On publish, your app is building the clientapp/dist folder and that's all you need. If you put the angular files in wwwroot, you're making aspnet use the static file middleware instead of the SPA middleware

Comment: I wish. Even if I remove the angular files from wwwroot, the application throws "Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: " and still throws the "cannot match any routes".

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my problem. Had a syntax error in my connection string in appsettings!